# Using gulp to create localized resource bundles

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat

I have a bunch of files in a resources directory:

- labels.no.js
- labels.en.js
- errors.no.js
- errors.en.js

I want to create one resource bundle per language so that I will server only one of these bundles to the client based on client's language. So I want to have this result:

- bundle.en.js (all en files from various directories)
- bundle.no.js (the same for no files)

I don't want to hardcode the languages (otherwise I could have copy/pasted), so I need some way to automatically "join" files in one bundle based on the suffix (so no matter how many languages I have, I will have the number of bundles equal to the number of languages grouped by suffix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it with help of gulp-group-aggregate:

```
var groupAggregate = require("gulp-group-aggregate");

gulp.task("buildResources:js", function () {
return gulp.src(["/sourcefolder"], { base: "." })
    .pipe(groupAggregate({
        group: function (file) {

            var extractResourceLocale = function() {
                var result = file.relative.substring(0, file.relative.length - 3); // remove ".js"
                var dotIndex = result.lastIndexOf(".");
                return result.substring(dotIndex + 1, result.length);
            }

            return extractResourceLocale(file);
        },
        aggregate: function (group, files) {

            var filesArray = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                filesArray[i] = files[i].relative;
            }

            var bundlePath = "bundles/result." + group + ".js";

            gulp.src(filesArray)
                .pipe(concat(bundlePath))
                .pipe(uglify())
                .pipe(gulp.dest("."));

            return {
                path: ".",
                contents: null
            }
        }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
```

});